# How to correctly use jq's in() function

Tags: jq

I'm trying to understand `in()` function of `jq`.

https://jqplay.org/s/BR1KbCjP8u

```
filter:
map( in(["ms", "is", "bad"]) )
input:
["apple","is","bad"]
```

I expected the output `[false,true,true]` because for each element of the input array:

1. "apple" is not in ["ms", "is", "bad"] so false
2. "is" is in ["ms", "is", "bad"] so true
3. "bad" is in ["ms", "is", "bad"] so true

Obviously this is wrong because I get error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot check whether array has a string key
exit status 5
```

What is wrong with this and how to correctly use the `in()` function when passing `["ms","is","bad"]` in the filter? I want to check if each element in the input array is found in this list.

Comment: Thanks for this question, illuminating... here's a filter that does give the original expected output, `[false, true, true]`, from the input: `map( in({"ms":null,"is":null,"bad":null}) )`. Just reading the error message and putting that together with @pmf's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `in()` incorrectly.

https://jqplay.org/s/FJcNTgplG6

```
filter:
map(in(["apple","is","bad"]))
input:
[3, 2, 1, 0]
output:
[
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true
]
```

It's testing if the indexes of the filter array are found in the input array.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you were looking for the `IN` (not `in`) function. Also, it takes a stream of elements, not an array.

```
map(IN("ms", "is", "bad"))
```

```json
[false,true,true]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/060XvkDHyS)

---

From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual):

> ### [in](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#in)
>
> The builtin function `in` returns whether or not the input key is in the given object, or the input index corresponds to an element in the given array. It is, essentially, an inversed version of `has`.

> ### IN
>
> This builtin outputs `true` if `.` appears in the given stream, otherwise it outputs `false`.

Comment: yep that is useful thx!